# When the Input is Empty alert is not working, How to Select and Delete the List Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]'
  });
});

$('#update').on('click', function() {
  $('#result').append('<li>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="todo-item" />' + $('#myText').val() + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove todo-item-del"></i>' + '</li>');
  // $('#myText').val("").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  // update value
  $('#myText').val('').change();
});
if ($('#myText').val().length != 0) {
  alert('Are you Kidding ? ;)')
}

$('#edit').on('mouseup', function() {
  console.log($('#myText'));
  $('#myText').attr("disabled", false).focus().select();

});
$('#myText').on('focus', function() {
  $('#myText').on("click", function() {
    $('#update').removeClass("gray_text");
    $('#update').addClass("show");
  })
})
$('.hide').on("click", function() {
  $('.hide').removeClass("show");
});

$('#result li').on('click', function() {
  alert('Clicked');
});
```

```css
input{
  padding:10px;
}
.editable_text{
  width:300px;
}
.glyphicon{
  padding: 10px;
  
}

#result{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
}

#result li {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:15px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    line-hieght:50px;
}
.todo-item{
    margin-right: 15px !important;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    color:green;
}
.todo-item-del{
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="editable_text">
    <div class="btns">
      <a id="edit" class="pull-left plus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to Add">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      </a>

      <a id="update" class="gray_text okay" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Click to Okay">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <input type='text' id="myText" placeholder="Add new goals" />
    <ul id="result"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I did so far, in this code I'm not getting the alert 'Are you kidding ? ' when the input is empty, and I'm not getting the alert when am clicking on the `li` in `#result`, which after selecting the `li` I should delete it by clicking remove icon.

Here is  the Fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/apL5vfj9/3/)

Comment: Well, you are asking if the length is *unequal* to 0. And the if-statement doesn't belong to any function. It is only executed once at start

Comment: Apart from above, you need to check condition on update button click handler.

Comment: you have to check the length of the input when **clicking the "okay" button**, but you only check the length once at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `update`-function as follows:

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {

    if ($('#myText').val().length == 0) {
        alert('Are you Kidding ? ;)');
        return; //end if item shouldn't be added
    }

    $('#result').append('<li>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="todo-item" />' + $('#myText').val() + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove todo-item-del"></i>' + '</li>');

    // update value
    $('#myText').val('').change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check condition in update button click handler and the check  condition should be `length == 0`

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#myText').val().length == 0) {
        alert('Are you Kidding ? ;)')
        return;
    }

    $('#result').append('<li>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="todo-item" />' + $('#myText').val() + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove todo-item-del"></i>' + '</li>');

    // update value
    $('#myText').val('').change();
});
```

Additionally, You can bind multiple events handlers like

```
$('#myText').on("focus click", function() {
    $('#update').removeClass("gray_text");
    $('#update').addClass("show");
});
```

And use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to manipulate properties like `disabled` instead of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

*To remove*

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*For your example*

```
$('#result ').on('click', 'li .glyphicon-remove', function() {
    alert('Clicked');
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

[image: jsFiddle]